# How do I make `mmm` omit the time-consuming doc build steps?

Tags: android-source

Working with the source code from AOSP, after I make a trivial change to a 
source file under `frameworks/base/core/java/android/`,
`mmm frameworks/base -j9` takes about 4 minutes.
A large portion of that time seems to be waiting for steps with names containing "Droiddoc" or "Docs droiddoc" to complete:

```
...
[ 14% 4/28] Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/api-stubs
[ 21% 6/28] //frameworks/base:test-api-stubs-docs Droiddoc [common]
DroidDoc took 102 sec. to write docs to out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/test-api-stubs-docs/android_common/docs/out
[ 28% 7/25] Docs droiddoc: out/target/common/docs/api-stubs
DroidDoc took 113 sec. to write docs to out/target/common/docs/api-stubs
[ 32% 8/25] //frameworks/base:api-stubs-docs Droiddoc [common]
DroidDoc took 115 sec. to write docs to out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/api-stubs-docs/android_common/docs/out
[ 40% 9/22] //frameworks/base:system-api-stubs-docs Droiddoc [common]
DroidDoc took 117 sec. to write docs to out/soong/.intermediates/frameworks/base/system-api-stubs-docs/android_common/docs/out
...
```

I really don't need or want any documentation to be built on every little incremental recompile.
Is there a way to omit all these doc-related steps?

I'd be interested in either a command line flag if there is one,
or a hopefully simple hack to one or more Makefiles and/or .mk files.

I've looked through the .mk files; in particular build/make/core/droiddoc.mk
seems relevant.  I tried cutting some wires in it without really understanding what I was doing, without success.

I'm hoping someone who understands how these .mk files are put together
will know how to do this easily.

I expect this will be of interest to anyone who runs `mmm` frequently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During `make` or `mmm` invocations, there are apparently two different kinds of build steps that build docs.
Each must be dealt with in its own way.

1. The build steps that have "Docs droiddoc" in their progress messages.  That string comes from `build/make/core/droiddoc.mk`.

   I was able to suppress these build steps as follows: delete all lines from `build/make/core/droiddoc.mk`, so it becomes an empty file.
2. The build steps that have "Droiddoc" in their progress messages.  That string comes from `build/soong/java/droiddoc.go`.

   I was able to suppress these build steps as follows: delete or comment out the last two blocks in the calling file `build/soong/java/androidmk.go`:

   ```
   func (jd *Javadoc) AndroidMk() android.AndroidMkData {
           ...
   }
   func (ddoc *Droiddoc) AndroidMk() android.AndroidMkData {
           ...
   }
   ```

I confirmed that it's no longer spending time building docs, on Darwin, by keeping an eye on the Activity Monitor during the build,
and verifying that `javadoc` processes no longer appear.

With docs omitted, `mmm frameworks/base -j9` after a small code change now takes 45 to 55 seconds, instead of 4 minutes.